# Problem with Running test on CodeWare.com

Tags: c

**is there any thing wrong with my code?** this a question from codewar and I am trying to solve, and it worked on atom but when I ran a test on website, it showed an error?

If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.

Finish the solution so that it returns the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below the number passed in.

Note: If the number is a multiple of both 3 and 5, only count it once. Also, if a number is negative, return 0(for languages that do have them)

link of the question https://www.codewars.com/kata/514b92a657cdc65150000006/train/c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sum_of_mul_of_3or5(int n)
{
  if(n<0){return 0;}
  int s = n,sum = 0,array[s];
  for(int i=1; i<n;i++)
  {
    array[i-1] = 0;
    if(i%3 == 0|| i%5 == 0){array[i-1] = i;}
    sum += array[i-1];
  }
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
  {
    printf("%d ",array[i]);
  }
  return sum;
}

int main(){


  int limit; printf("Enter a limit number: "); scanf("%d",&limit);
  int sum = sum_of_mul_of_3or5(limit);
  printf("\n");
  printf("%d",sum);


return 0;}
```

Comment: What exactly is the error?

Comment: Maybe the VLA... why did you not paste in the exact error message?

Answer (score -1):

Your algorithm is O(N) - it should be O(1).

Count how many 15 under given n. e.g 200, there are N=13 chunks of length 15. Every 15 (from K to K+14) you get K,K+3,K+5,K+6,K+9,K+10,K+12, total 7N+45. Sum them up, simply use N(N+1)/2*7+45N. Then add back the extra ending parts you have not accounted between 195 and 199.